# Get arrays with null values, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a query where I try to get some value under some conditions, the problem is that at the end I get a list of arrays (ex. 4), but the fields value is null. Not sure why.. if some conditions are not met I expect to get nothing, not an array with null values.

```
$questions = MyModel::select(
        'answer_statistics.id',
        'answer_statistics.paragraph_id',
        'paragraphs.free_text as free_text',
        'paragraphs.id as paragraph_id',
        'questions.best_match as best_match'
        )
        ->whereNotNull('answer_statistics.paragraph_id')
        ->leftJoin('paragraphs', 'answer_statistics.paragraph_id', 'paragraphs.id')
        ->leftJoin('questions', 'paragraphs.question_id', 'questions.id');

    if($excepted_questions){
        $questions->whereNotIn('answer_statistics.id', $excepted_questions);
    }

    if($confidence_specs->best_match){
        $questions->whereNotNull('questions.best_match');
    }

    if($confidence_specs->votes != 0 && $confidence_specs->weight != 0){
        $questions->where('answer_statistics.votes', '<=' , $confidence_specs->votes)
        ->orWhere('answer_statistics.weight', '<=' , $confidence_specs->weight);
    }

    $questions->inRandomOrder()
        ->limit(4)
        ->get();

    dd($questions->get());  // here I get 4 arrays with null values..
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the error/issue? What are you trying to achieve? What is it that you are expecting?

Comment: If i don't have rows then my $questions will be null.  Now in my $questions I have a list of arrays that have null values, witch is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

To remove null values from an array, you can use [filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-filter)

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, null, false, '', 0, []]);
$collection->filter()->all();
// [1, 2, 3]
```